# List up values that meet a certain criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tabs in the same sheet.

The first tab has a list of companies' names in column B, and in column BD I put a mark for companies I have had a meeting with.

In the second tab, I want to list up the companies that I have put a mark on in the first tab.
Meaning, if in tab 1 there is a mark in column BD, I want the name of that company to appear in column A of tab 2.

I have tried vlookup, index, if... but somehow I can't make anything work.
Does anyone have an idea for me..?

For example I tried this:

```
=index('Tab1'!B3:B6000,small(index(('Tab1'!BD3:BD6000<>"●")*5000+row('Tab1'!BD3:BD6000),),Row(A7)))
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `filter()` function, like this:

`=filter('Tab1'!B3:B, 'Tab1'!BD3:BD = "●")`

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: OH MY GOD you solved it!!!!
Thank you so much!!!!